# How to access JSON arrays properly?

Tags: javascript, json

i have an external JSON file in this format `{ "easy" : [1, 14],"hard":[12, 10]}`. How do I access all the elements of the json file and how do i find if a key is already present in it and fetch only that data. Example: I want to access only the values associated with "easy", How do i do it?

Comment: the file name is userscores. so i would access it like userscores.easy. I know that but how do i check if easy is already present or not? Beacuse when i check it like (if(userscores.easy)) im getting as undefined

Comment: Did you retrieve the file via an AJAX request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.contains` or `.indexOf` with `Object.keys(userscores)`.

```
var userscores = JSON.parse(jsonString);

if ((Object.keys(userscores)).contains('easy'))
{
    var data = userscores.easy;
}
```

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/71Lxzh60/) using `.indexOf`.

Comment: here the easy or hard input is given by the user and is stored in a var type. so when i do userscores.input, its giving an error as cannot access of undefined.

Comment: Ah.  Just use `userscores[input]`.  Here's an updated fiddle using that: http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/71Lxzh60/1/

Comment: suppose i wanted to add a new key value pair like "med" : [2, 45]. How could I do this?

Comment: You mean after you fetch the data from the external file?  Just add that property to your parsed object (`userscores`): `userscores.med = [2, 45];`  OR `userscores["med"] = [2, 45];` http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/71Lxzh60/2/

Answer (score 2):

Read the file content into a string and use `JSON.parse`. Use typeof != 'undefined' to check the object key:

```
var json = '{ "easy" : [1, 14],"hard":[12, 10]}',
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
if(typeof obj.easy !== 'undefined'){
   alert(obj.easy[0]);
}
```

Comment: `alert(obj.easy[0])` only returns `1` so `alert(obj.easy)` should be enough since the OP seems to want all data from the `easy` key

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to actually get a hold of the file in your JavaScript code.

Below is a simple AJAX request that, when the JSON is received, turns it into a JavaScript object so it is easier to work with:

```
function ajax() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // for IE7+, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var json_object = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); // takes the response text from the server (the contents of the JSON file) and turns it into a JavaScript object.
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "http://www.myserver.com/my_json.json", true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your JSON is assigned to a variable called `userscores`. You can access objects in JSON using the `.` notation, i.e. `userscores.easy` to access the array `[1, 14]`.

```js
var userscores = {
  "easy": [1, 14],
  "hard": [12, 10]
};

console.log(userscores.easy);

for(i = 0; i < userscores.easy.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li"),
      text = document.createTextNode(userscores.easy[i]);
  
  li.appendChild(text);
  
  document.getElementById("easy").appendChild(li); 
}
```

```html
<ul id="easy"></ul>
```